# Protractor exports nice reports to file (pdf, doc, html or something like that)

Tags: report, protractor

I want to make protractor at the end of its tests to save prety formated reports as PDF, HTML, or something with styling (customizing abilities will be perfect). Unfortunately the only think that I managed to find is "jasmine-spec-reporter" and it is doing descent reports but in the console... so its not a solution for me.

EDIT: I have try "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter" as Tony Vincent suggested below and **I'm looking for something similar**. But I can't figure out whre the saved files are, because path like "**/directory/**" is strange for Windows machine and I'm not sure exactly what is mean. I have searched the whole machine for exported report, but couldn't find one.

Also other similar suggestions are welcomed

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

Comment: everything looks good but where are the exported files. The config says baseDirectory: '/tmp/screenshots' and I can't find such directories.... I was looking in my project folder, in my protractor folder, on my hard drive root folder and I can't fid anything (also there is no error in the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with **protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter** (be careful there are a lot of bugs in this library)